# Как вывести текст на изображение C#

Tags: c#

Помогите пожалуйста. Сам вывод текста на изображение получается. но теряются пропорции размера текста и расположение его. Как возможно реализовать вывод с сохранением ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чёрный текст, туда куда поставил и хочу видеть. Красный то, что получается. А если у PictureBox размер поставить AutoSize, то вроде норм получается.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bit = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        string pathSave = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}/1.jpg";
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bit);
        graphics.DrawString("Тестовый текст", new Font("Arial", 64, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Red),
            new RectangleF(label1.Location.X - this.Location.X, label1.Location.Y - this.Location.Y, label1.Width, label1.Height));
        bit.Save(pathSave, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    Label label1 = new Label();
    

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Location = new Point((Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X), (Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Тестовый текст";
        label1.AutoSize = true;
        label1.Font = new Font("Arial", 64, FontStyle.Bold);
        pictureBox1.Controls.Add(label1);
    }
```

Comment: Вот просто интересно: а по́стить на программерском форуме вопрос без строки кода даже, без объяснения, как этот текст выводился, какие классы использовались, какие методы и т.д. - это такой тонкий троллинг или тест на ясновидение отвечающего?)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я добавил необходимую информацию. Извините, вопрос задаю в первый раз. Не думал, что вообще ответят.

Comment: Координаты бывают клиентские и экранные. Нужно пересчитывать одни в другие. Смотрите методы PointToClient, RectangleToClient, PointToScreen, RectangleToScreen.

Comment: Кстати, именно это вы делаете при задании `label1.Location`. Где-то ещё координаты не переведены. Очевидно, в `graphics.DrawString` прямоугольник создан неверно.

Comment: Слушайте @Petrov, Когда в PictureBox SizeMod указан как AutoSize тогда координаты и размер букв не уменьшаются. Если я включаю к примеру Zoom, тогда нарушаются координаты и размер текста.

Comment: Можно ли как то пропорционально уменьшать размер шрифта и положение его на изображении. Так как подозреваю, что дело именно в сжатии картинки при использовании у свойства SizeMod - Zoom. Картинка уменьшается, а текст нет.